# Windows Linux Bash bad variable name when running /bin/sh -c "$(curl -fsS https://install.airshipcms.io)"

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, curl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

everything was working until I changed my mobo/cpu and I'm not sure what the error message means.

After running the install command

```
/bin/sh -c "$(curl -fsS https://install.airshipcms.io)"
```

my windows ubuntu bash shell returns

```
Starting Airship Launcher installation for ubuntu Linux64                                                                                                                                                                                       
Will install version 2.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Downloading https://install.airshipcms.io/Linux64/airship-2.1.1.tar.bz2                                                 
To /tmp/AirshipLauncher.65/airship-2.1.1.tar.bz2                                                                        
Added ~/.airship-bin to $PATH in ~/.profile                                                                             
/bin/sh: 504: export: (x86)/Intel/iCLS: bad variable name
```

My guess was that because I already had it installed pre-upgrade of the mobo/cpu the variable name is already taken in the ~/.profile ? I'm not sure how to edit it, when I ran cat ~/.profile it rendered a bunch of unreadable characters.
thank you.

edit: I've tried reinstalling my linux shell, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the fix is to replace sh with bash so the working command was

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsS https://install.airshipcms.io)"
```

credit goes to this guy https://github.com/probonopd/PowerShell/commit/2441d99a7405b488dc9289789edb636dc2cdcdfc